# VB.NET convert date string ddMMyyhhmmss to Date Object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a string that holds a value in the format of ddMMyyhhmmss.

Example `240512024707`

I need to be able to convert this date to a real .NET Date object.

I am currently using CDate but it seems CDate does not recognize the format, is there any way of specifying the string format to CDate ???

`row.Item("NoteDate") = CDate(n.noteText.Substring(0, 12).ToString).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the string with the date, you know the exact format string - use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) (or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) if you wish to avoid the potential exception being thrown):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("240512024707", "ddMMyyhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```